# Why does Safari pick a grey color instead of the white color

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm currently working on a site for a company and they wanted a menu on the top of the page. Everything works fine in most modern browsers, exept Safari. In safari the color of the text in the menu is grey unless you hover the menu items fast and after that they stay white or jump back to grey. The other browsers all show the right white color.

I made a screenshot of the Firefox(IE 9 and Chrome) version and the Safari version.
http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/8493/bothd.png

Here is the fiddle i'm currently testing in:
http://jsfiddle.net/StevenVenmans/RNNPj/

Comment: You are using two color declaration, why? Maybe it would help to use only the hexadecimal one.

Comment: You're defining RGBA and then overriding with an RGB value, if you want to use RGB [as a fallback](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/) then you need to define it first.

Comment: @NCode - he's doing this because he wants an RGBA colour, but allowing a fallback for browsers which don't support RGBA. Quentin's answer correctly explains why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using two kind of color definitions in the css, remove the first one  and try, i am talking about

```
 1. color: rgba(255,255,255,1);    
 2. color:#FFFFFF;`
```